# How to perform three different operations and import the module to another python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My aim:
To create a python Modules with 3 functions:

```
Sample input1: bob
output:
Yes it is a palindrome
No. of vowels:1
Frequency of letters:b-2,o-1
```

```
=int(input("Enter number:"))
temp=n
rev=0
while(n>0):
    dig=n%10
    rev=rev*10+dig
    n=n//10
if(temp==rev):
    print("The number is a palindrome!")
else:
    print("The number isn't a palindrome!")
```

```
ch = input("Enter a character: ")

if(ch=='A' or ch=='a' or ch=='E' or ch =='e' or ch=='I'
 or ch=='i' or ch=='O' or ch=='o' or ch=='U' or ch=='u'):
    print(ch, "is a Vowel")
else:
    print(ch, "is a Consonant")
```

In a new file I am giving :

```
import test
def main():
    while True:
         word = input("enter a word")
         test.isPalindrome(word))
         test.count_the_vowels(word))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If I call my module in another file, it automatically does all the  functions. But I want to give input(name) in this new module and check the output for it.But this is asking input again since name is present before def function in the other file. How to overcome this?

I am new to coding.Please be as elaborate as possible.Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are callinginput and passing the value in each function call to your 3 funcs. Instead call input once and store its value like `name = input("Enter name: ")` then pass name to each of the function calls like `isPalindrome(name)`

Comment: Since name=input("") is present before def blocks, when I create a new file and import this file, my aim  for this new file is to check palindrome,vowel count, letter count for the input I give here.But it is asking for name twice because I give an input statement for name in new file too.How to overcome this? @ChrisDoyle

Comment: dont put the code for input in your file you are importing. define it only in the file that your run the code and import the funcs like: `import myfuncs; name=input("name: "); myfuncs.isPalindrome(name)`

Comment: If I do this, NameError occurs saying 'name' is not defined in both the files @ChrisDoyle

Comment: Can you elaborate and if possible show the changes in the code,please? @ChrisDoyle

Comment: Bruno already posted an answer which is exacty how i was suggesting to do it

Comment: yes but if I try bruno's code in new module that again executes the program twice i.e., asks for input twice.If I remove name=input("") from the original module and then execute it it results in name error since name is not defined in the first module.@ChrisDoyle

Comment: post your stack trace. you are clearly not understanding something

Comment: I've edited exactly what I am doing in my code.Please let me know where I am going wrong@ChrisDoyle

Comment: Stop calling the functions inside the module where they are defined. Just have in the module file the functions and thats it. then in your other file import the module file, ask for the name via input then call the functions of the modules one by one passing the name to them

Comment: Can you show it in code? It is still showing errors.@ChrisDoyle

Comment: Is that the actual content of your module? You are only showing blocks of code, not functions. Where are the function definitions?

Comment: Please clarify your question, see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

If you're question is "how to ask for the name only once and pass it to both function", the answer is simple: in your main.py script (or test.py or however you named it), add this:

```
import yourmodule # where you defined your functions

def main():
    while True:
         word = input("enter a word (ctrl+C to quit) > ")
         yourmodule.isPalindrome(word)
         yourmodule.count_the_vowels(word)
         # etc

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Now note that your assignment doesn't say you have to do this - it says:

> Import the module in another python script and **test the functions by passing appropriate inputs.**

Here, "passing appropriate inputs" can also be understood as having a harcoded list of words and calling your functions with those names... IOW, a [unit test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing).

Comment: If I call my module in another file, it automatically does all the three functions. But I want to give input(name) in this new module and check the output for it.ie in my new file I give ``` import (name of my file) input("Enter name"). But this is asking input again since name is present before def function in the other file. How to overcome this?

Comment: I've edited my code please check. @bruno desthuilliers

Answer (score 1):

After trying several times to explain in the comments here is a brief example. so make a file with your functions. then in your other file import your funcs file then ask user for name and pass it to the funcs. This is just an example of how to define functions in one file and then call them from another. you probably want to look at your funcs as they should probably return values rather then just print stuff otherwise your calling file wont be able to validate the function since it will receive nothing back.

**MyFuncs.py**

```py
def hello(name):
    print(f"hello {name}")

def goodbye(name):
    print(f"goodbye {name}")
```

**stackoverflow.py**

```py
import MyFuncs

name = input("Name: ")
MyFuncs.hello(name)
MyFuncs.goodbye(name)
```

**OUTPUT: **when running the stackoverflow.py script

```
Name: Chris
hello Chris
goodbye Chris
```